# wordpress horizontal scrolling section in mobile view

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, elementor

I have created a section in wordpress, Which have multiple columns. but in mobile view it display one under another .  I want to display columns in a single row . How in the mobile version to display multiple columns side by side with horizontal scrolling , and not one under the other? how to create a horizontal scrolling section in wordpress mobile view using elementor ? please help me .
Thanks in advance .

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Create a container and add as many columns as you like with a custom class "card-content".
you have to add a custom CSS class to the parent node of
the columns container so for this I have added a custom CSS id for 1st column "cardContent1"
then I've added custom js to the page:

```
var cardContent1 = document.getElementById("cardContent1");
var parentNode = cardContent1.parentNode;
parentNode.classList.add("card");
```

then add custom CSS into the page

```
.card {
  background-color: #fff;
  min-width: 100%;

}
.card{
    display: flex;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.card {
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.card::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.card-content{
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

That's it.